# Is there a way to use setDividerLocation on the bottom componet?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a `JSplitPane` with a vertical split. The top component is a table which is in a `JScrollPane`, and the bottom component is a detailed description of a row. The bottom component always have the same number of elements, so essentially it stays the same height.

Right now, I am using `setDividerLocation` to position where the pane is being split. If I put `100` into it, the top portion will be `100px`, if `500` then the top will be `500px`. But if I re-size the `JFrame`, then the top component is still 100px and the bottom component is really big.

I was wondering if there is a way to set the divider location based on the bottom component instead of the top component?

Sorry if I didn't explain it well, if what I said is still confusing, please let me know and I can try to explain it better.

------ EDIT ------

Thanks to ControlAltDel for figuring it out. This is what my code looks kinda looks like now:

```
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
splitPane.setTopComponenet(new JTable());
splitPane.setBottomComponent(new JPanel());
splitPane.setResizeWeight(1); // This gives the top component priority when the window is resized
```

Comment: *"bottom component .. stays the same height."* I do not see the advantage of using a `JSplitPane` for this case.  Put the bottom component at the `PAGE_END` of a `BorderLayout`, with the scroll pane in the `CENTER`.

Comment: You do make a valid remark. I guess before, this program needed the bottom component to be resized, but it has changed a lot, I might go back to BorderLayout. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight(double)